# Can't understand how recursion works in this example

Tags: java, recursion

I was given the following code:

```
public int func(int n){
  if(n == 1)
     return 2;
  else 
     return 3 * func(n-1)+1;
}
```

I can understand recursion in things like factorial and fibonacci, but for this one I cant.
I tried to trace the logic:

```
if n is 3:
return 3 * func(2) + 1
return 3 * func(1) + 1
return 3 * 2 + 1
return 7
```

I always end up with 7 with any other number and I know this is wrong because I get different values when I run the program.  Can you help me understand how recursion works here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is self-explanatory, if you need more informations just comment !

```
if n is 3:
return 3 * func(2) + 1
return 3 * (3 * func(1) + 1) + 1 //func(2) is equals to 3 * func(1) + 1
return 3 * (3 * 2 + 1) + 1 //func(1) is equals to 2
return 22
```

Answer (score 2):

- If `n` is 1 it returns `2` (so `func(1) = 2`).
- If `n` is 2 it returns `3 * func(1) + 1`, which is `3 * 2 + 1 = 7` (so `func(2) = 7`).
- If `n` is 3 it returns `3 * func(2) + 1`, which is `3 * 7 + 1 = 22` (so `func(3) = 22`).
- If `n` is 4 it returns `3 * func(3) + 1`, which is `3 * 22 + 1 = 67` (so `func(4) = 67`).
- ...

And so on. In other words, when `n = 1` it simply returns 2 and it all other cases it returns the value for `func(n - 1)` times three and with one added.

Answer (score 1):

if n is 3

```
func(3)
=3*func(2)+1
=3*(3*func(1)+1)+1
=3*(3*2+1)+1
=22
```

if n is 4

```
func(4)
=3*func(3)+1
=3*22+1
=67
```

Answer (score 1):

You're close, but missing a key point:

```
func(3) is: 3 * func(2) + 1
func(2) is: 3 * func(1) + 1
func(1) is: 2

Therefore, func(2) is 3*2+1 = 7.
And func(3) is 3*7+1 = 22
```

Answer (score 1):

when `n=3` you get

```
func(3) = > return 3 * func(2) + 1
```

where `func(2)` is

```
func(2) = > return 3 * func(1) + 1
```

where `func(1)` is

```
func(1) = > return 2
```

once you combine them you get that

```
func(3) => return 3 * (3 * (2) + 1) + 1

func(3) => return 22
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to reinput that value you get for the deepest recursion call into the previous level and so forth.

```
func(1) = 2
func(2) = 3 * func(1) + 1 = 7
func(3) = 3 * func(2) + 1 = 22
func(4) = 3 * func(3) + 1 = 67
```

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule a recursive method has two parts,

1. The part for solving primitive problem, here in your example is
   *if(n == 1)
   return 2;*
2. The part for dividing the problem into smaller problems so that finally it falls under part 1 (primitive problem)
   *else
   return 3 * func(n-1)+1;*

This is the very nature of **Divide and Conquer** algorithms that tend to divide the problem into smaller pieces in each round until they became solvable. Then by joining the solved pieces, the original problem gets solved.